# Flask cannot import name app in python3.4

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I am a basic python user. And now I have to use Flask because of class
The environment is Python3.4(venv) and flask in CentOS 6.8 
Use it in Vmware. And I have created the first application in it 
The source is https://linux.cn/article-5044-1.html (a chinese website)
I've did all steps but run.py could not work. my folder is named test, In the first time I did all steps same about this web page. but from app import app could not work. I changed it but still not work)

```
File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
from test import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
```

Is there any problem in my development environment or something wrong?

There is the source code about that page

```
[leo@linux-vps python3.4-flask] mkdir  app
[leo@linux-vps python3.4-flask] mkdir app/static
[leo@linux-vps python3.4-flask] mkdir app/templates
[leo@linux-vps python3.4-flask] vim app/_init_.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from app import index
[leo@linux-vps python3.4-flask]vim app/index.py
from app import app

@app.route('/')
  def index():
import subprocess
 cmd =     subprocess.Popen(['ps_mem'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out,error = cmd.communicate()
memory = out.splitlines()    

return
```

Comment: and what do you have in folder `test` ? Did you create file `__init__.py1` with `app` ?

Comment: there is mistake - name `__init__.py` needs two `_` at the beginning and two `_` at the end.

Comment: Here is my _init_.py 
 from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from test import index  
It still not work

Comment: It works! Thx so much! But why this file should named two_ ?

Comment: python has many special functions with two `_`  - ie. in code you have `__name__`. `__init__.py` inform Python to treat this folder as module/package